# Disable css hover effect when ng disabled is true for custom button

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am try to disable custom `button` and disable(pointer) function is working fine.

The problem is when we `hover` on the button, `hover` is still works. Hence I need to disable hover as well.

I need to apply `ng-disable` for multiple custom `buttons` and I can not override css for every button.

[jsfiddle.net/q8r4e/1389/](http://jsfiddle.net/q8r4e/1389/)

Code:

```
<button class="bt1" ng-disabled="true" >BUTTON</button>
<button class="bt2" ng-disabled="true" >BUTTON</button>

.bt1{
background-color: #e38000;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 135px;
}
.bt1:hover{
background-color: #ffff00;
    color: #999;
}

.bt2{
background-color: #33b3e3;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 135px;
}
.bt2:hover{
background-color: #a2ddf4;
    color: #999;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
.bt1:hover{
    background-color: #ffff00;
    color: #999;
}
.bt2:hover{
    background-color: #a2ddf4;
    color: #999;
}
```

Use

```
.bt1:not([disabled]):hover{
    background-color: #ffff00;
    color: #999;
}
.bt2:not([disabled]):hover{
    background-color: #a2ddf4;
    color: #999;
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/q8r4e/1391/)

EDIT:

To have common CSS for ALL the disabled buttons you can just add

```
button:disabled, button:disabled:hover{
    background-color:red;
}
```

and replace the color red with whatever you desire.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/q8r4e/1395/)

Comment: Here problem is css is already written for all buttons. Can't we make general css for all buttons?

Comment: Yes, you can. However, both the buttons have different colors for active and inactive states

Comment: If you want to common out the `:hover` logic then you will have to define generic style for disabled buttons.

Comment: Yes, I need single css for all disable buttons and it should disable hover functionality